# Can a WordPress domain point to an openshift hosted application?

Tags: wordpress, dns, cross-domain, openshift

I bought a WordPress domain and built a blog, but now I want to use the domain I bought in WordPress to redirect to an application in [OpenShift](https://www.openshift.com/).

I mean, when acessing my WordPress domain "example.com" my OpenShift application should show up.

Is it possible?

Any other alternatives to use the domain bought in WordPress without losing more money are valid.

OBS.: The OpenShift application is not a WordPress blog.

Comment: You should probably contact the WordPress.com support department and ask them about it.

Answer (score 0):

You possibly need to transfer the domain to OpenShift, as WordPress.com is a service for WordPress blogs.